# "farne di tutti i colori" in English

Tags: translation, idiom-requests, italian

Does anyone know the English translation for "farne di tutti i colori"? It's an Italian expression meaning "do all sorts of things" The literal translation would be: *to do something in every colour*. It usually has negative connotations.

Is there an English idiomatic expression with the same meaning? For example, a good translation of "un altro paio di maniche" is "a horse of another color", which I heard in a movie, whereas "an entirely different matter" is not a faithful translation in my book.

Comment: This is a question about English: you are asking for an English phrase (even if in order to do so you describe it partially in terms of an Italian one). It is off topic here. On the other hand, on english.SE or ELL.SE it is usual for people to ask for words or phrases meaning so-and-so.

Comment: You could ask the mods to migrate it over to E&LU. Flag your question with a custom reason and ask there. It's an interesting question, but I agree with DaG.

Comment: This very much depends on the situation and on the context. The answer posted below is actually quite good as it gives an appropriate idiom for each context. Could you provide a sentence, or the specific context where you would use this expression or idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for something about a child or a joking situation, you can use something like "TO BE A BUNDLE OF MISCHIEF".
In a context more serious, if someone says you a lot of things ("me ne ha dette di tutti i colori") you can use "HE CALLED ME ALL SORT OF NAMES".
If your original situation is like "passarne di tutti i colori", you can use "TO GO THROUGH THE MILL".
In a confusing situation ("ne vediamo di tutti i colori") you can use "WE SEE ALL SORTS".